# How can MVVM Toolkit be used on winform?

Tags: .net, winforms, mvvm, toolkit

I noticed that it is claimed here that it can be used on winform, but I don't know how to use it? Can someone give an example?

Here is a link to the official website：
https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVzex.png)

I tried using MVVM in WinForm and came across this framework